# How to Extract a Number from HTML Tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Please, how do I extract the following items from the HTML code pasted below.

1. Open price only (7.50)
2. Volume figure only (11,393,304)
3. Today's High (7.80)
4. Today's Low (7.15)

```html
<div class="col-1">
<!-- previous close  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Previous Close</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.50</span>
</div>
<!-- open  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Open</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.50</span>
</div>
<!-- Volume (daily)  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Volume</span>
<span class="detail-value">11,393,304</span>
</div>
<!-- 3Month (90 day avg volume)  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">3m Avg Volume</span>
<span class="detail-value">13,978,777</span>
</div>
<!-- Today's High  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Today’s High</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.80</span>
</div>
<!-- Today's Low  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Today’s Low</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.15</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "scrap a number"? Exactly what do you want to happen? (Do you want teh numbers deleted but leave the commas?) What is the trigger for this event to occur? (Do you want user to click a button and that causes the action to happen? Or on page load? Or...?)

Comment: Thanks Gibberish for your offer to assist. I want to extract the open figure(7.5 wrt this example), the volume figure (11,393,304), Today's High figure and Today's low figure and store then in a database. My major issue for now is how to extract these items from the BeautifulSoup object i have in the form of html. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What I have understood from your problem is that: given some text (eg: Open), you want to find the number associated with it (eg: 7.50).

My solution would be to first find the span tag with the text, and then find it's sibling.

```
def getNumberGivenText(text):
    pattern = re.compile(text)
    #find the span tag with this text
    span_tag = soup.findAll("span", text=pattern)[0]
    #find it's next sibling
    num_tag=span_tag.find_next_sibling()
    #get the value
    number=num_tag.string
    return number

print(getNumberGivenText("Open")) #7.50
print(getNumberGivenText("Today’s Low")) #7.15
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: @DarlingtonEmeagi If it worked can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try. basically iterates through the tags and grabs the ones in the `get_list`

```
html = '''
<div class="col-1">
<!-- previous close  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Previous Close</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.50</span>
</div>
<!-- open  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Open</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.50</span>
</div>
<!-- Volume (daily)  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Volume</span>
<span class="detail-value">11,393,304</span>
</div>
<!-- 3Month (90 day avg volume)  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">3m Avg Volume</span>
<span class="detail-value">13,978,777</span>
</div>
<!-- Today's High  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Today’s High</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.80</span>
</div>
<!-- Today's Low  -->
<div class="section-quote-detail group">
<span class="detail-label">Today’s Low</span>
<span class="detail-value">7.15</span>
</div>
</div>'''


import bs4 

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'section-quote-detail group'})

get_list = ['Open','Volume',"Today’s High","Today’s Low"]

results = pd.DataFrame()
for element in data:
    if element.select('span.detail-label')[0].text in get_list:
        label = element.select('span.detail-label')[0].text
        value = element.select('span.detail-value')[0].text
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[label, value]], columns = ['label', 'value'])
        results = results.append(temp_df).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.